# Getting wrong time after subtraction

Tags: php, strtotime

Hello I am using `strtotime` function to subtract time but I am not able to getting such true value of it.

```
$time = strtotime('00:00:00');
$time1 = strtotime('23:00:00');


$t = $time - $time1;

echo "diff".$t1 = date('H:i:s',$t);
```

But am getting `$t = 2:00:00` Instead of i get `1:00:00`

Any one have idea whats gone wrong ?

Comment: try date('H:i:s',strtotime($t));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$time = strtotime('00:10:00');
$time1 = strtotime('23:00:00');

$t = $time - $time1;

$hours   = floor(($t - (($t/ 86400)* 86400)) / 3600);

$minutes = floor(($t - (($t/ 86400) * 86400) - ($hours * 3600))/60);

echo "
".$hours.':'.$minutes;

its give you right diff. time for same days .

Answer (score 0):

try to add `strtotime()` on changing format

```
date('H:i:s',strtotime($t));
```

Comment: Hey its not giving proper result for minutes its just for hours can have any idea